# ¿Como puedo pasar una variable en un archivo Javascript a otro?

Tags: javascript

Tengo la duda de como seria posible pasar x variable de un archivo `Javascript` a otro archivo del mismo formato, es decir, de `archivo.js` a `archivo2.js`.

En el siguiente ejemplo, necesito pasar la variable `respuesta` (que se encuentra en el *archivo.js*) a otro archivo (*archivo2.js*), la variable la obtengo de un resultado mediante `Ajax`.

Código `Javascript:`

```
var fecha = $("#primeraFecha").val();
var datos = new FormData()

datos.append("fecha", fecha)

$.ajax({
   url: "....",
   method:"POST",
   data: datos,
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   dataType:'JSON',
   success: function(respuesta){
       console.log(respuesta);
   }
});
```

En el `Html` los `scripts` los enlazo de la siguiente manera:

```
    <script src="js/archivo.js"></script>
    <script src="js/archivo2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola @Victor lo puedes hacer usando el **localstorage** del navegar que te permite guardar el valor de una o mas variable. En esta página que te dejo tienes la explicación de como se usa [Ir al enlace](https://rolandocaldas.com/html5/localstorage-en-html5)

Comment: Lo que espero que alguien te explique en alguna de las respuestas (que estan bien) es que no pasas una variable de un archivo a otro, si no que al incluir los dos archivos en un html, es como que todo el codigo estuviera en un solo archivo. y al definir las variables globales, las ven todas las funciones

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lo comentado por los [@Canabix](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4314/28035) y [@Michael Salazar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/135506/michael-salazar) es correcto, pero explicare un poco mas.

En el Navegador al crear una variable o  una funcion en la raiz de un documento JavaScript se alojan en el Objeto **`window`** [pero ten en cuenta el alcance de las variable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/106067/28035) daré un ejemplo a continuación:

```js
var mi_variable ="mantequilla soup";
let mi_otra_variable = "variable local"
const const_variable = "constante";
console.log("accediento con los distinto tipos de declaracion con window")
console.info("window var =",window.mi_variable)
console.info("window let=",window.mi_otra_variable)
console.info("window const=",window.const_variable)
console.log("fin")
console.log("accediendo a funcion y a variables del mismo nombre" )
function ejemplo(){
  var mi_variable = "chispas se llama igual"
  console.info("local=" , mi_variable);
  console.info("window var=" , window.mi_variable);

}
console.info("window ejemplo=",window.ejemplo)
ejemplo()
console.log("fin")
```

De igual forma puedes llenar de basura el objeto window, así que pensemos en otra forma, ehhmmm callbacks, suponiendo que tu funcion ajax es la siguiente que se encuentra en `archivo1.js`:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "....",
   method:"POST",
   data: datos,
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   dataType:'JSON',
   success: function(respuesta){
       resp = respuesta;
   }
});
```

y en `archivo2.js` tienes algo como:

```
function retornarRespuesta(val){
//aqui el codigo

}
```

Las funciones tambien se guardan en window, entonces cambiemos un poco el codigo ajax y quedaria asi :

```
$.ajax({
   url: "....",
   method:"POST",
   data: datos,
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   dataType:'JSON',
   success: window.retornarRespuesta
});
```

> Por ultimo, si tienes que pasar variable de un archivo Javascript a
> otro por favor valida la implementación probablemente no debe estar alli, lo ideal es crear el archivo JavaScript con las acciones a realizar por cada documento HTML

Pregunta relacionada:
[¿Cómo se usa la función Window en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/260278/c%c3%b3mo-se-usa-la-funci%c3%b3n-window-en-javascript)

Comment: Tu respuesta me ha ayudado mucho! Tengo una duda con respecto a `window`, ya que soy nuevo utilizando Javascript, como afectaría esto (almacenar datos en window) con respecto al navegador?

Comment: Declara siempre tus variables prefiere let o const , lee la pregunta que te coloque para que comprendas un poco más

Answer (score 2):

Debes establecer una variable global.

```
var fecha = $("#primeraFecha").val();
var datos = new FormData();
var resp;

datos.append("fecha", fecha)

$.ajax({
   url: "....",
   method:"POST",
   data: datos,
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   dataType:'JSON',
   success: function(respuesta){
       resp = respuesta;
   }
});
```

En tu archivo archivo2.js la puedes llamar sin dificultad, pero no podrás acceder a este valor "resp", a menos que sea llamada por una función que se ejecute después de haberse ejecutado el ajax.

Para este problema, puedes hacer que tu ajax sea síncrono.

Comment: No puedes hacer una petición asíncrona síncrona

Answer (score 2):

Puedes declarar una variable global antes de llamar a tus archivos JS o incluso en el primer archivo JS.

```
 <script>
    mi_variable_global= '';    
 </script>
 <script src="js/archivo.js"></script>
 <script src="js/archivo2.js"></script>
```

Luego aquí puedes asignar el valor a tu variable global.

```
var fecha = $("#primeraFecha").val();
var datos = new FormData()

datos.append("fecha", fecha)

$.ajax({
   url: "....",
   method:"POST",
   data: datos,
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   dataType:'JSON',
   success: function(respuesta){

   //AQUI LE ASIGNAS EL VALOR Y PUEDES USARLO EN TU OTRO ARCHIVO JS SIN PROBLEMAS
   mi_variable_global= respuesta;

   console.log(respuesta);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes declarar una variable fuera de tus funciones de javascript para despues solo accedes desde otro script

ejemplo:

```
    //este puedes der tu script1
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var varGlobal = "variable";
    </script>
   //este puedes der tu script2
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(window.varGlobal);
    </script>
```

en tu segundo archivo recomiendo agregues ajaxstop para acceder al valor una vez que se recibió respuesta de la petición

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
   console.log(window.varGlobal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Una posible forma es importando el `archivo.js` desde `archivo2.js`, sería así:

archivo.js

```
export function ajax() {
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json());
};
```

archivo2.js

```
import { ajax } from 'archivo.js';

ajax().then(respuesta=>console.log(respuesta));
```

En el html (Cuidado que el `type="module"` es fundamental):

```
<script type="module" src="js/archivo2.js"></script>
```

En este ejemplo estamos exportando una promesa que sería mas o menos el caso que tienes.