# ¿Cómo modifico una variable global desde una función sin que esta última sepa el nombre?

Tags: javascript

Como indica el título, quiero modificar una variable global desde una función sin acceder a la misma directamente, quedando así:

```
var a = 5;

console.log(a);

midificaVariable(a);

console.log(a);

function modificaVariable(b)
{
    b--;
}
```

la variable a en el primer log tendría un valor de 5 y en el segundo log un valor de 4.

La idea de esto es usar una función para editar distintas variables independientemente del nombre de las mismas.

---

Si la variable `a` es un objeto o un arreglo, cuando se pone como argumento se crea una referencia, haciendo que si yo modifico la referencia, estoy modificando la variable global.

Comment: puedes acceder por el objeto [window](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/290555/28035) pero esto solo es para navegadores, de igual forma no es buena practica modificar las variables globales en metodos, creo que deberias explicar mejor la pregunta de lo que quieres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder ejecutar la función, si o si sabrás como se llama la variable global, así que esta función de ejemplo se adaptaría al requerimiento, ya que esta en ningún momento sabe el nombre de la variable.

```js
var a = 5;

var modificaVariable = function(nombreVariable, variable) {
    variable--;
    window[nombreVariable] = variable;
};

modificaVariable('a', a);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 3):

Si la función "modificaVariable" lo que hace es modificar a "a", lo más sencillo y rápido que se me ocurre es que devuelvas el valor que deberá tener, es decir, algo así:

```
var a = 5;

console.log(a);
a = modificaVariable(a);
console.log(a);

function modificaVariable(b){
    return --b;
}
```

Mostrará en pantalla

```
5
4
```

Comment: Es mejor usar esta forma, para que a futuro se pueda hacer mantenimineto y tracking al código