# variable y función con el mismo nombre

Tags: javascript

En el código siguiente:

```js
function prueba() {
    console.log("Esto es una función");
}

var prueba = "Esto es una variable";

prueba();
```

Obtengo el error:

```
prueba.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: prueba is not a function
```

No entiendo por qué la variable y la función no pueden tener el mismo nombre. Son dos cosas diferentes.
Gracias.

Comment: Estás reasignando el puntero `prueba` de una función a un *string* y no se permiten referencias duplicadas por ambigüedad. Y esto se debe principalmente a que las funciones en Javascript son variables, también.

Comment: Ya lo entendí.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Usa el identificador `let` en tu varibale y te notificará que no puedes usar dicho identificado por que ya ha sido declarado mas o menos así: **`"SyntaxError: Identifier 'prueba' has already been declared
`**, entonces no puedes compartir el mismo nombre para la variable y  tu función

Comment: [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/290555/28035) te aclarara basicamente estas diciendo var prueba = ()=>... y luego var prueba = 2; es decir estas sobreescribiendo la variable prueba

Comment: por cierto lo que dice @VRoxa tiene razon tu funcion la escribe el interprete algo aso ´var prueba = function(){}´

Answer (score 3):

### Pregunta:

- ##### variable y función con el mismo nombre

---

```
  function prueba ()
  {
    console.log( "Esto es una función" );
  }

  var prueba = "Esto es una variable";

  prueba();
```

### Respuesta:

- ##### ¡Esta, me la sé!

---

1. **¿Sabes la diferencia entre `var` y un `let` o `const` en Javascript?**

- `var` tiene *coercion*, es decir, obliga a la declaración de la variable a ascender en el *scope* mientras que `let` y `const` se mantienen dentro de él.

2. **¿Y qué rayos es el *scope*?**

- El *scope* es el *ámbito, espacio, lugar, cajón* de trabajo o uso, donde algo o alguien realiza una acción o vive.

3. **¿Y entonces qué es la *coercion*?**

- La *coercion* es el acto de obligar a alguien a hacer algo, que por lo general no quiere hacer.

---

En tu código cuando declaras la variable con `var` estás escribiendo `var prueba;` arriba de todo, de manera implícita,
Por lo que al llamar a `prueba();` el compilador se encuentra una variable llamada `prueba` y ella no es una función.

- ##### Solución: (buenas prácticas)

  - No volver a usar **`var`**, en su lugar usa:

    - **`let`** para valores que pueden o van a cambiar durante la ejecución del código.
    - y **`const`** para valores que no deben cambiar, esto no quiere decir que no lo puedan hacer, si no que no deben cambiar.
  - Sigue la siguiente regla para los nombres de tus identificadores (variables, funciones, etc.)

    - Las variables son cosas, **usa un sustantivo** p.e. `let miPrueba = ... ;` o `const miPrueba = ... ;`.
    - Las funciones son acciones, **usa verbos en infinitivo** p.e. `escribirMiPrueba(){};`.
    - No uses palabra genéricas como identificador, no dicen nada sobre lo que son o lo que hacen, sé explícito, **¡aquí el tamaño no importa!**.
    - Y si es posible usa palabras en inglés, que es lo que se recomienda.
- Esto te ayuda a no cometer **errores tontos** que son difíciles de encontrar y depurar.
- Y ayuda, a los demás, a saber que es y que hace cada cosa.